# No implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer: How to insert a JOIN table value in create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

For a room reservation I would like to include options for the room.

As the options are dynamically generated in the form as they are dependent on the selected room_type, I tried building them in the create action.

The options and its join table reservation_options seem to be inserted correctly into my params, but I am not able to properly assign the option_quantity value of the join table. It gives me the error message `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`

**Params**

```
 "authenticity_token"=>"o4KMn/lP9tYwpDhZTsBFEYHLfwWVanYYZ6bdrkK84QO4vHbcDIzlGp1TiH/+J06Z0UwRby9obkK4J22E0Plsvw==",
 "reservation"=>
  {"rooms"=>{"room_type"=>"185"},
   "arrival"=>"2019-10-25",
   "departure"=>"2019-10-26",
   "room_id"=>"266",
   "reservation_contact_attributes"=>
    {"first_name"=>"John", "last_name"=>"Doe", "street"=>"Amstreet", "street_number"=>"", "zipcode"=>"4049", "city"=>"Gent", "country"=>"", "email"=>"john@hotmail.com", "phone"=>""},
   "payment"=>"paid"},
 "reservation_options_attributes"=>[{"option_id"=>"110", "option_quantity"=>"1"}, {"option_id"=>"109", "option_quantity"=>"1"}],
 "commit"=>"Save & proceed to additional options",
 "hotel_id"=>"109"}
```

models

```
class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reservation_options, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :options, through: :reservation_options
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :reservation_options
end

class ReservationOption < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :option
  belongs_to :reservation
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :option
end

class Option < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :room_type
  has_many :reservation_options, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :reservations, through: :reservation_options
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

reservation controller

```
def create
    @user = current_user
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])
    @reservation = Reservation.new(reservation_params)
    @reservation.hotel = @hotel
    authorize @reservation
    if @reservation.save
      params[:reservation_options_attributes].each do |reservation_option|
        if @option = Option.find_by(id: reservation_option[:option_id])
          @reservation.options << @option
          # output 1 for reservation_option

          reservation_option = @reservation.reservation_options.where(option: @option)
          # output 2 for reservation_option

          reservation_option.update(option_quantity: reservation_option[:option_quantity])
          # Error message

        end
      end

      redirect_to root_path
    else
      @room_type_list = @hotel.room_types
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

output 1 for reservation_option

```
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"option_id"=>"110", "option_quantity"=>"1"} permitted: false>
```

output 2 for reservation_option

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<ReservationOption id: 62, option_id: 110, reservation_id: 142, option_quantity: nil, created_at: "2019-10-25 12:27:45", updated_at: "2019-10-25 12:27:45">]>
```

Comment: What do those relationships look like in the models? Is it a `has_many :through`?

Comment: Than you for the response. I added the relevant models, and yes it has a ```has_many:through```

Comment: Right, so you don't need to push to revervation's options. Just to its revervation_options

Comment: The option_quantity indeed is on reservation_options, if that's your question?

Comment: I solved it by identifying ```@option_quantity = reservation_option[:option_quantity] ``` and pushing it this way instead ```reservation_option.update(option_quantity: @option_quantity) ```

Comment: Still that's too much unnecessary work. You have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :reservation_options`. Could have simply put the join object at `params[:reservation][:reservation_options_attributes]`, permit this in `reservation_params` and that's it! Now `Reservation.create(reservation_params)` will create everything.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate feedback. I'm not sure if  I can follow you, how would this look like in the controller? In the params something like this; ```params.require(:reservation).permit(:accommodation_id, :arrival, :departure, :payment, :reservation_contact_id, option_ids:[],reservation_options_attributes: [:id, :option_id, :option_quantity, :_destroy,
        options_attributes: [:id, :name, :room_type_id, :description, ``` and how would it translate to the create action?

Comment: Yep, pretty much this. Only no need for `options_attributes` since options exist already. Just an `option_id` in `reservation_options_attributes` should suffice.